# Getting started with OracleSQL grammar for Java

Tags: antlr3, antlrworks

I'm trying to get started with http://www.ibrezina.net/OracleSQL.tgz

So far, I've performed the following:

```
wget http://www.ibrezina.net/OracleSQL.tgz
tar xvzf OracleSQL.tgz
cd OracleSQL
make
```

which results in the following error:

```
gcc -ggdb -O0 -fno-inline -I. -I/usr/include/qt4/QtCore  -I/usr/include/qt4/QtGui  -I/usr/include/qt4  -I/home/ivan/devel/antlr-3.3/runtime/C/include  -I/home/ivan/devel/antlr-3.3/runtime/C -c OracleSQLParser.c -o OracleSQLParser.o
In file included from OracleSQLParser.c:45:0:
OracleSQLParser.h:537:23: fatal error: antlr3.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
Makefile:60: recipe for target `OracleSQLParser.o' failed
make: *** [OracleSQLParser.o] Error 1
```

I'm not interested in building the 'c' dialect.  I only want to generate the Java lexer and parser.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'm not interested in building the 'c' dialect. I only want to generate the Java lexer and parser.
>
> How can I do this?

That grammar is not so portable: it contains a lot of embedded C code.

If you want to create a Java lexer and parser, you need to remove the `language=C` from the `options { ... }` block (defaulting to the Java target) and then translate all C code between `{` and `}` to a Java equivalent (which is quite a bit of work, I'm guessing).

Comment: There is a script `cgrammar2java.pl` in the archive and also Java commands in the Makefile that made me think a Java lexer and parser could be created.

Comment: I just tried that script, but it does not produce a valid grammar.